# How to open file selector/browser from command line Mac OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

Is it possible to open a file selector from the command line in Mac OSX? I may not be using the proper term, so what I am looking for is the window that pops up when one needs to select a file from within a program.

For example, using File > Open in Xcel or Word.

[image]

This selector has options to select a file to open or cancel, allowing one to browse various directories. Is there a way to invoke this from the command line?

Thank you

Comment: This is an NSPanel call in ObjectiveC or similar - I know of no call directly  - but you could write a wrapper to do what you want :)

Comment: Thank you @cgseller for your comment. Ideally I would be able to call this from within a python script. I figured the easiest way to do that would be to invoke the command line from within said script. Any idea of an analog within the context of python?

Comment: You would have to import a third party or write your own.  (e.g. http://pymotw.com/2/EasyDialogs/)